# how to replace all numbers in a string with a number plus a special character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this ,

```
(1 AND 2 ) OR (2 AND 3)
```

I need to replace this string all numbers with a numbers + special character (like `1@,2@`), the result should be like this ,

```
(1@ AND 2@ ) OR (2@ AND 3@),
```

So I tried the following ,

```js
var d = "(1 AND 2 ) OR (2 AND 3)"
console.log(d.replace(/[0-9]/g, "@"))
```

but it will only produce a result like ,

```
(@ AND @ ) OR (@ AND @)
```

my expected output is ,

```
(1@ AND 2@ ) OR (2@ AND 3@)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try including the match in the output with `$&`:

```js
const str = '(1 AND 2 ) OR (2 AND 3)'
console.log(str.replace(/\d/g, '$&@'));
```

You could also use (new) lookbehind, that way the *boundary* is matched, but not the number itself:

```js
const str = '(1 AND 2 ) OR (2 AND 3)'
console.log(str.replace(/(?<=\d)/g, '@'));
```

Comment: This is a better solution than I proposed. I'll delete mine. :)

Comment: $& stands for ?

Comment: @AhammadaliPK See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace It substitutes in the entire matched pattern. Similarly, you can use `$1` or `$2` to substitute in the first or second matched *group* (enclosed in parentheses in the regex)